# python-tkinter problema con command

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona correctamente:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()

Opc = IntVar()

def opcion():
    if Opc.get() == 1:
        etiqueta.config(text="Seleccionado H")
    else:
        etiqueta.config(text="Seleccionado M")


Radiobutton(raiz, text="Masculino", variable=Opc, value=1, command=opcion).pack()

Radiobutton(raiz, text="Femenino", variable=Opc, value=2, command=opcion).pack()

etiqueta = Label(raiz)
etiqueta.pack()
raiz.mainloop()
```

Sin embargo cuando en **command** cambio `opcion` por `opcion()`

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/POO/RadioButtons.py", line 14, in
>   
>       Radiobutton(raiz, text="Masculino", variable=Opc, value=1, command=opcion()).pack()   File
>   "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/POO/RadioButtons.py", line 11, in opcion
>       etiqueta.config(text="Seleccionado M") NameError: name 'etiqueta' is not defined

Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia en llamarlo con `()` y sin ello. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Teoría: funciones como parámetros

Supón la siguiente definición:

```
def hola():
    return "Que tal"
```

`hola` es un identificador que se refiere a una función. En python esos identificadores pueden asignarse a otras variables, o pasarse como parámetro.

Ejemplo de asignación a otra variable:

```
ejemplo = hola
```

El resultado es muy diferente si pones los paréntesis tras `hola`, así:

```
ejemplo = hola()
```

en este segundo caso *estás ejecutando* la función indicada por el identificador `hola`, y *el resultado* de esa ejecución (es decir, lo que la función haya retornado) es lo que asignas a `ejemplo`. Por tanto `ejemplo` contendría la cadena `"Que tal"`.

En el primer caso, en cambio estarías asignando directamente el identificador `hola` a la variable `ejemplo`. A partir de este punto `ejemplo` es otro identificador que se refiere a la misma función, de modo que podrías hacer `ejemplo()` para llamar a la misma función que cuando escribes `hola()`, y así `print(ejemplo())` imprimiría `"Que tal"`.

Tu caso es similar, pero estás pasando el identificador de función como parámetro. Este es un ejemplo de una función que recibe otra como parámetro:

```
def ejecutor(funcion):
    print("Voy a ejecutar la función")
    resultado = funcion()
    print("El resultado ha sido: {}".format(resultado))
```

Como ves, esta función recibe un parámetro llamado `funcion`, y lo usa en `funcion()` para invocar a la función que haya recibido como parámetro. Podríamos usarlo así:

```
ejecutor(hola)
```

Es decir, pasándole el identificador de la función `hola`. Dentro de `ejecutor` su parámetro `funcion` se referirá entonces a `hola` y cuando llegue a la línea `funcion()` será como si hubiera ejecutado `hola()`.

Como ya puedes comprender esto es muy diferente a:

```
ejecutor(hola())
```

ya que en este caso estaríamos *ejecutando* `hola()` y pasando como parámetro *el resultado*. Es decir, dentro de `ejecutor`, `funcion` contendría la cadena `"Que tal"` y al llegar a `funcion()` dará un error porque una cadena no se puede ejecutar.

### En tu caso

Tienes otro problema añadido, y es que la función que le pasas (`opcion`) contiene errores. En concreto hace uso de la variable `etiqueta` que no es conocida. Cuando erróneamente pasabas `command=opcion()` estabas ejecutando en ese momento la función `opcion()`, y por tanto los errores que había en ella se manifiestan inmediatamente.

Cuando lo haces de la forma correcta, `command=opcion`, la función no se ejecuta todavía, sino que queda almacenada en el componente `RadioButton`, y se ejecutará cuando el usuario interactúe con ese componente (y entonces se produciría el error debido a la variable `etiqueta` desconocida, pero parece que entonces esa variable ya existe, pues la defines más abajo, lo que de todas formas me parece mal diseño).